# SFTP from another network?

Tags: raspberry-pi, webserver, sftp

I've been using SFTP to access and modify the contents of a Raspbery Pi web server. I'll be moving it off my internet connection and onto someone else's, and I was wondering if there is still a way I can easily access the files similar to the SFTP connection I've been using.
If worst comes to worst I plan on just using remote access in and downloading the files from Dropbox when I need to.

Answer (score 1):

**Well... Yes...**

...If you have access to the NAT(router) settings, you can forward the ssh(sftp) port so it becomes externally available.

External IPs for private subscribers are usually DHCP/Dynamic though. Trying to connect after an IP change makes for an annoying experience.

You could set up **dynamic DNS**, and let the Pi auto-update it. That will let you connect to a simple hostname instead of trying to connect to ever-changing IP addreseses.

**Security:**

Do keep in mind that you should **not expose** such a port to the wide world if you use the default usernames with simple passwords.

Enabling **only** keyfile-authentication is a good idea. This disables all password entry for authentication. You should also make sure all remote logins are explicitly disabled for the root account.

In addition to this, there's a program named fail2ban which will limit login attempts and block connections from anyone repeatedly failing to authenticate.

I would also create a new user with sudo privileges and disable or remove the pi user since default accounts are what most attackers try first.